# Elastic Search Complex Logical Query (SQL to ElasticSearch Query)

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

My document schema is as follows.

**Post**

```
Id
Title
Body
Privacy -> Values can only be ["Me", "Anyone", "Team"]
UserId
```

What I want to do is retrieve all documents, but exclude documents where

```
Privacy = "Me" 
and 
UserId != "My-User-Id"
```

The SQL equivalent code is

```
SELECT * from Posts
WHERE (Privacy = "Anyone" OR Privacy = "Team")
OR (Visibility = "Me" AND UserId = 'My-User-Id')
```

I want to know how I can convert that SQL to the Elastic Search equivalent.
Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. You already know what do you want to search and already have an equivalent SQL query, but what is the specific problem that you found?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Ah sorry for the confusion. I want to convert that SQL query to the Elastic Search equivalent.

Comment: Can't you use [SQL access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html)? It allows you to use SQL to query Elasticsearch indices. It even has a translate API to convert SQL queries into native Elasticsearch queries.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I didn't even know that was a thing. I tried it just now and I got it to work. Thank you so much, you're a life saver.